# <script>タグを </body>タグの後ろに記述しても良い？

Tags: javascript

**[MDNのWebGLチュートリアル](https://github.com/mdn/webgl-examples/blob/ea1c73ff3ec8d069d890cda0495052bb44a8b073/tutorial/sample1/index.html)で、`<script>`タグを `</body>`タグの後ろに記述しているのですが**

---

**Q1.`<script>`タグを、`</body>`タグの外に記述しても良い？**

---

**Q2.`<script>`タグを、`</body>`タグの外に記述するメリットは？**
・どうしてこのような書き方をしているのでしょうか？
・WebGLだから？？

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Q1.<script>タグを、</body>タグの外に記述しても良い？

ダメです。

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-html-element

```
Content model:
    A head element followed by a body element
```

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element

```
Contexts in which this element can be used:
    Where metadata content is expected.
    Where phrasing content is expected.
    Where script-supporting elements are expected.
```

> Q2.<script>タグを、</body>タグの外に記述するメリットは？

とくにないと思われます。</body>の直前に書いても同じですし、他の場所に置いて `defer` 属性を付けてもよいです。このHTMLを書いた人のミスでしょう。

追記:
そもそも、HTMLパーザによって</body>後に書いてるタグはbody要素の子として追加される と仕様に書いてありました。DevTools などで見ると<script>が移動しているのがわかります。
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing-main-afterbody

```
12.2.6.4.19 The "after body" insertion mode
   → Anything else
     Parse error. Switch the insertion mode to "in body" and reprocess the token.
```